# Remover html tag, mas manter <br> Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-tags

Estou com duvidas sobre como remover as tags html, mas manter apenas `<br>`

Esse código remove as tags, mas eu gostaria de manter o `<br>` e talvez outras tags.

```
function removeHtmlTag(strx,chop){ 
    if(strx.indexOf("<")!=-1)
    {
        var s = strx.split("<"); 
        for(var i=0;i<s.length;i++){ 
            if(s[i].indexOf(">")!=-1){ 
                s[i] = s[i].substring(s[i].indexOf(">")+1,s[i].length); 
            } 
        } 
        strx =  s.join(""); 
    }
    chop = (chop < strx.length-1) ? chop : strx.length-2; 
    while(strx.charAt(chop-1)!=' ' && strx.indexOf(' ',chop)!=-1) chop++; 
    strx = strx.substring(0,chop-1); 
    return strx+'...'; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se seu código já retira todas as tags html atualmente, você pode, antes de passar sua função, substituir todos os `<br>` por uma `string` específica, como por exemplo `~br~` e depois que passar pela sua função, transformar novamente todas as strings `~br~` por uma tag `<br>`

```js
function trocarTexto() {
    var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace("original", "modificado");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<p>Clique no botão para trocar o texto exemplo:</p>

<p id="demo">Texto original!</p>

<button onclick="trocarTexto()">Clique aqui</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Eu estou aprendendo javascript ainda, poderia me dar um exemplo de como fazer isso?

Comment: @jonyboy Adicionei o exemplo na resposta.